# How to change android background every ??? seconds?

Tags: android, animation

I want to change my Relative layout's background every 10 seconds with fade in/fade out animation.
So I found

```
//Transitiondrawable
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewObj.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(transitionTime);
```

But it supports only 2 Drawable and I want to add more
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First implement MyAnim.java class as below:

```
public class MyAnim extends Animation {


    private final RelativeLayout view;
    private int targetBackGround;


    public MyAnim(RelativeLayout view, int tagetBackGroundColor) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetBackGround = tagetBackGroundColor;
    }
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        view.setBackgroundColor(targetBackGround);
    }


    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.targetBackGround = color;
    }
}
```

Then add below code to your activity and call that animateBackground() method wherever you want:

```
    private MyAnim backgroundAnim;
    private int i;

    private void animateBackground(){
        final RelativeLayout animLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.animLay);
        final int colors[] = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.CYAN, Color.DKGRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA};
        backgroundAnim = new MyAnim(animLay, colors[i]);
        backgroundAnim.setDuration(1000);
        animLay.startAnimation(backgroundAnim);

        backgroundAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                if (i == colors.length - 1) {
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
                backgroundAnim.setColor(colors[i]);
                animLay.startAnimation(backgroundAnim);


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank's it is definitely what I want
Now how can I use Fade in animation for changing background colors

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own loop, something like:

```
 int delayBetweenAnimations = 10000;

    for (int i = 0; i < yourImagesArray.length ; i++) {

        int delay = i * delayBetweenAnimations;

        yourImageview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //set your image and animation here
            }
        }, delay);

    }
```

Another way is to use recursive animation:

```
          @Override    
           public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
               if(check_if_you_Still_want to_loop){
                    //rerun your animation
               }
           }
```

Comment: in setting background how can I set array for background?

Comment: int[] imageList = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2...};

Comment: I knew this but I asked how to set array for background
thank you very much my friend

Comment: What's the difference? isn't the background an image?

Comment: Yes, what is the method to set Background of view with array
like this view.setBackground(R.drawable.ic);??

Comment: viewObj.setImageResource(imageList[index]);